# Get-PSDrive c used space in MB and GB

Tags: powershell

```
$size = get-psdrive c
echo $size.used
```

How do I get the value of C drive used space in Both MB and GB?
I have looked around and could not find a proper answer. pls help. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you have the value in GB or MB, you could easily convert it.  If this is for a program, please give more details on how and why you want this information.

Answer (score 5):

Basic Byte conversion would work. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692684.aspx

```
$drive = get-psdrive c
$used_size = $drive.used
write-host "MB:" ($used_size / 1MB)
write-host "GB:" ($used_size / 1GB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"

Comment: It's not an actual answer to his specific question on the use of Get-PSDrive, it's a detour. It would be forgivable if it gave him the answer that he's looking for, but it doesn't.

Comment: Agree, but am also curious why Sean Rhone prefers (or thinks there is some reason not to use `get-psdrive`) `get-wmiobject` over `get-psdrive`?